# Couchbase high disk compared to data usage (still growing)

Tags: couchbase

Any idea why couchbase disk usage can be growing each day, when data usage is at about the same level?

Current disk usage vs. data usage: 143GB / 5.27GB

I understand this might be related to data fragmentation, but running bucket compaction doesn't help. I never had such issue before. It started to happen few days after migration to Couchbase Community Edition 4.0.

[image]
[image]

Edit:

Recently I performed full backup, CB reinstallation, restore and it worked ok for several days, but today the problem came back again.

In error.log I can see some issue with compaction process, details below:

```
[stats:error,2016-03-04T00:19:25.545+01:00,ns_1@127.0.0.1:<0.1403.0>:stats_reader:log_bad_responses:170]Some nodes didn't respond: ['ns_1@127.0.0.1']
[stats:error,2016-03-04T00:19:25.785+01:00,ns_1@127.0.0.1:<0.1946.0>:stats_reader:log_bad_responses:170]Some nodes didn't respond: ['ns_1@127.0.0.1']
  [ns_server:error,2016-03-04T00:19:25.905+01:00,ns_1@127.0.0.1:<0.1946.0>:menelaus_web:loop:184]Server error during processing: ["web request failed",
                                 {path,"/pools/default/buckets/rtb/ddocs"},
                                 {method,'GET'},
                                 {type,exit},
                                 {what,
                                  {error,
                                   {badrpc,
                                    {'EXIT',
                                     {noproc,
                                      {gen_server,call,
                                       ['capi_ddoc_manager-rtb',
                                        {foreach_doc,
                                         #Fun<capi_utils.5.35130662>},
                                        infinity]}}}}}},
                                 {trace,
                                  [{ns_couchdb_api,rpc_couchdb_node,4,
                                    [{file,"src/ns_couchdb_api.erl"},
                                     {line,162}]},
                                   {capi_utils,full_live_ddocs,3,
                                    [{file,"src/capi_utils.erl"},{line,172}]},
                                   {menelaus_web_buckets,
                                    do_handle_ddocs_list,3,
                                    [{file,"src/menelaus_web_buckets.erl"},
                                     {line,1316}]},
                                   {request_throttler,do_request,3,
                                    [{file,"src/request_throttler.erl"},
                                     {line,59}]},
                                   {menelaus_web,loop,2,
                                    [{file,"src/menelaus_web.erl"},
                                     {line,162}]},
                                   {mochiweb_http,headers,5,
                                    [{file,
                                      "/home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/sherlock-unix/couchdb/src/mochiweb/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                                     {line,94}]},
                                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                    [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}]
[ns_server:error,2016-03-04T00:19:27.446+01:00,ns_1@127.0.0.1:compaction_new_daemon<0.1196.0>:compaction_new_daemon:log_compactors_exit:1266]Compactor <0.2138.0> exited unexpectedly: {error,
                                           {badrpc,
                                            {'EXIT',
                                             {noproc,
                                              {gen_server,call,
                                               ['capi_ddoc_manager-rtb',
                                                {foreach_doc,
                                                 #Fun<capi_utils.3.35130662>},
                                                infinity]}}}}}. Moving to the next bucket.
```

Comment: Could you check the data and index folders and post which files in particular are growing? Or just all the files sizes, if you could paste the list somewhere.

Comment: There are few large files (3GB, 22GB, 45GB, 77GB) in @indexes/bucket_name/ folder, for example main_b4c3a20a7f38940ba43b618b33a4fd4a.view.467

Comment: And view compaction is turned on and set to something like 30%?

Comment: Yes, I was even triggering compaction manually on the bucket, but it frees just small part of the space used.

Comment: I'm guessing the view definitions haven't changed either? Hmm, interesting. Is this behavior consistent on all nodes? And are the same files growing out of control, or different ones?

Comment: View definitions were restored from backup during upgrade as it was not possible to perform the upgrade from 3.x to 4.0 (different pkg name), but since then they weren't changed. It's a single node with XDCR replication to ElasticSearch.

Comment: I just realised that this started not few days after upgrade, but rather a month after it. In this period we observed high load on CB node due to XDCR replication (goxdcr processes running on 100% CPU each - AFAIK known bug in 4.0) and an indexer (related to N1QL?). 31st Jan we decreased number of XDCR Nozzles from 2 to 1 and dropped N1QL indices. This helped much with CPU usage. I'm not sure if this is related to what we observe now, but just in case.

Comment: I'm thinking now about performing data backup, CB reinstallation, data restore.